# Google in app purchases google play store on firebase : )

Tags: firebase, in-app-purchase

I am a young female developer, but currently i am building a project for a big client in our company,

I have a question, actually one of you can probablly lead me in the right direction:

I have a firebase account and an app with in app purchases - the thing is in app purchases will actually contain videos which i would like to store on firebase servers and download uppon purchase! Can someone lead me in the right direction on how to implement this the easiest way?

Ps., I know i am a rookie but i really do not want to look like an idiot on next months meeting ; )

Warm regards, Lana

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres honestly no easy way to achieve protecting a file/folder for a specific group of users with firebase cloud storage. You can do checks by changing the folders metadata or using custom tokens, but then you need a server for that etc...

If you wish to remain in a firebase only environment, the easiest way would probably be to have the protected videos hosted in a protected folder from all clients. When the user purchases a video, then send a request a CloudFunction along the lines of..

```
userClaimsToHaveBoughtAccessToVideo(userId, sku, token, videoId){
// 1. use the googlePlay billing API to verify that the user did indeed purchase the item
// 2. if they did, then store that in read-only node of the database like: /purchasedVideos/userId/videoID/
}
```

Then if a user wants to download a video, create a function along the lines of...

```
userWantsToDownloadAVideo(userId, videoId){
 // check the database to see if the user has the video
 // if they do, copy the video file to a folder like /userId/videos/...
}
```

Then the video will appear in a personal folder for which the security rules are easy to setup.

When the user downloaded the video to their device send a call to a function along the lines of..

```
userDownloadedVideo(userId, videoId){
  // delete video from the user's folder, to save space
}
```

Another option would be to host the videos on a different platform entirely, one that has an API and allows it's files to be password protected. (then simply store the access password after verifying IAP in the database, read only for the user), so they can use the other API to download the videos. For security you might want to have a daily job which regenerates the password every day and updates the database..

Comment: Thank you for your detalied answer, i seem to have a better understanding now - you and my night reading both helped : ) The only i think we missunderstood each other is - i do not need users to upload anything to the server- users would only download content from the companies store - i was looking into the Firebase Hosting they have a good CDN network i think that should be the right choice?

Comment: I didn't mention users uploading anything, for your usecase the most complicated thing is protecting your videos from those who haven't bought them. But yes, firebase (google cloud storage) is a solid option if you can figure everything out.

Comment: Yes i was thinking about that also, I have to look into the in app purchases process- i am not sure who is handling the download call process the android API or the user end...If the API is handling the request and i setup the links in the console i think that the security should not be a problem, isn that the case?

Comment: Linxy, do you think that user authentication would be enough to secure the files?  That would mean that only authenticated users (signed in to google for instance) would have access to the files? That sounds good enough for me but im not too savy in the security are...

Comment: Yeah, and it's likely the best if you use products from firebase/google cloud, and security rules integrate tightly with the provided authentication methods.